# Nuxt + External script -> Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, nuxt.js

If you use `Nuxt` and have any external script which raises `Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened.`, below you can find solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution 1 - If you need the script globally.

Simply use `vue-meta` (already included into Nuxt) as you would do with other scripts. Add it to `layouts/default.vue`:

```
<template>
  ...
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    ...

    head () {
      return {
        script: [
          {
            hid: 'any-label-for-the-script',
            src: 'SCRIPT_URL'
            // async: true,
            // defer: true
          }
        ]
      }
    },

    ...

    // If you need to run SOME_FUNCTION from downloaded script
    mounted () {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef
      SOME_FUNCTION(param1, param2, ...)
    }
  }
</script>
```

#### Solution 2 - If you need script just on some route/component.

1. Install [postscribe](https://github.com/krux/postscribe): `npm install --save postscribe`
2. Create `plugins/postscribe.client.js` file with content:

```
import postscribe from 'postscribe'

export default (context, inject) => {
  inject('postscribe', (elementId, scriptCode) => {
    postscribe(elementId, scriptCode)
  })
}
```

3. Inside `nuxt.config.js` add just created file:

```
export default {
  ...
  plugins: [
    ...

    { src: '~/plugins/postscribe.client.js' }

    ...
  ],
  ...
}
```

4. In your component do this:

```
<template>
  <div id="add-script-here" />
</template>

<script>
  ...

  mounted () {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-useless-escape
    this.$postscribe('#add-script-here', '<script src="SCRIPT_URL"><\/script>')

    // If you need to do something onload, then instead of the line above do it like this:
    // this.$postscribe('#add-script-here', '<script onload="DO_SOMETHING_ONLOAD_HEAR" src="SCRIPT_URL"><\/script>')
  }

  ...
</script>
```

Usually script should be added to `head` or `body`, but it seems that `postscribe` can not do this, so lets use `add-script-here`.